# Cannot select person account fields in Custom Metadata Field or Particle relationships

Tags: custom-metadata, person-accounts, metadata-relationship

Given a Custom Metadata Type with an Entity Definition Metadata Relationship field ("Account Object" in screenshot), and a Field Definition Metadata Relationship field ("Person Account Phone Field"), I would expect that, in an org with Person Accounts enabled, I could select the Account object for the Entity, and select a Person Account field such as "Mobile" (`PersonMobilePhone`) for the Field.  However, I cannot.  The list of available fields includes `IsPersonAccount`, but does not include any of the `Person*` fields included on Person Accounts.

MDT Config:

[image: MDT Config]

Field options:

[image]

I then tried adding a Particle Definition field to the MDT; that made available `PersonAccount`-exclusive particles `FirstName`, `MiddleName`, `LastName`, which are particles of the standard `Name` field, as well as Standard Account particles like Billing Street, but still did not show Email or Mobile, or `PersonAccount`-only particles like Mailing Street or Other Street.

I have checked the documentation, known issues, Ideas, SFSE, and the internet at large, and I cannot find any documented limitation of Field- or Particle- Definition Metadata Relationship fields with respect to Person Accounts, nor can I find anyone else asking about this issue.  Is this a true limitation, am I doing something wrong, or is this a platform issue?

**Edit to add:** Since I'm working in a scratch org, I tried manually setting the field I wanted in the `.md-meta.xml` source file and pushing my changes; this failed with the message `Person Account Phone Field: bad value for restricted picklist field: Account.PersonMobilePhone`.